# How to call a method on an Android Fragment to start an activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, lifecycle, onresume

I have an Android application that's using a SectionsPagerAdapter to create 3 separate fragments. What I would like one of the fragments to do is to automatically call a method (which launches an activity) whenever the user navigates to it from a tab bar. For example, right now I'm using the on resume() method to launch the activity. I also have a button set up to do it.

However, when I trace it through the debugger, the onResume() is only called when the fragment is first created. I've tried setting the fragment to null and recreating it from the SectionsPagerAdapter, but still none of the lifecycle methods are called. I've also set up a separate method in the fragment to launch  the activity and calling it from the SectionsPagerAdapter before returning the adapter, but that doesn't launch it either - it just shows the display.

As I mentioned, the display has a button which allows the user to launch the activity manually, but that means the user has to press a button twice - once to get to the page, and once to launch the activity.

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Interesting problem.  Can you post some of your code, I'd like to reproduce and see if I can get it working.

Comment: why not call startActivity() at onTabSelected() method

Comment: Thanks for the offer, Dan, but  it was originally created by a third-party and I don't know if I'm authorized for that.

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet - I ended up doing something like that - actually calling a method on the Fragment from OnTabSelected. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Call `startActivity()` at `onTabSelected()` method.